# PWM to DC conversion for measuring average power of a photosensor

Tags: pwm, filter

I want to use [this](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Mr9jhiYAYh5i_rNsxE_QXS13VSZLGZJ2/view?usp=sharing) photodiode to monitor average power of a pulsed laser where its optical pulse train's pulse width is 0.5 ns and pulse period is 333 ns. I want to obtain the DC output of the pulse train and calibrate it to monitor the average optical power. So it is like PWM to DC voltage conversion and since the photodiode is much slower than the pulse (due to junction capacitance) I first thought it will already output the DC average of the pulses.

Here is the circuit I want to use:

[image]

And here are simulations based on the photodiode model given in the datasheet:

[image]

Above in the first case there is no Rload or Rload is extremely big. In this case, as you see the voltage increases up to 150 V.

In the second case/circuit, I added Rload(330 Ω) to lower that output voltage in the first case. But now the ripple becomes very apparent. But response time is fast.

In the this case/circuit, I also added C4 (2.2 µF) which lowered the ripple.

My questions are:

1. What is happening in the first case? Will the output increase that much in reality? If it will, then the photodiode will be forward biased and will be damaged. But is that really what would happen? Or am I missing something in the simulation?
2. My aim is to obtain a DC voltage representing the average optical power and measure it with an MCU's 12-bit ADC. I'm planning to use the third Output3 circuit along with a non-inverting opamp if gain is needed. If it makes sense, should I first filter as in the Output3, or better to first amplify and then filter after the opmap?

Comment: The voltage even without load can't really increase beyond the open circuit voltage of the diode (photovoltaic characteristic). The model with a simple current source doesn't capture this voltage limit.

Comment: what is open circuit voltage of the photodiode in question?

Comment: You're powering the circuit with 2.6v, so think of that as the limit. If you really blast the diode with a lot of power it will give you slightly more due to the photovoltaic effect, but that will be highly nonlinear and not useful for measuring. Probably best to limit your output to be significantly less than 2.6v.

Comment: But how can I modify the simulation so I see more realistic plot? What is missing in my simulation? And how about 2nd question?

Comment: Instead of modulated current source, it would be more accurate to represent it as a voltage source in series with a modulated resistance (low when illuminated)

Comment: You're simulating a simple linear approximation of the real circuit, so the output is only meant to be roughly correct over the narrow range of current over which the diode is useful as a photo detector. You could improve the simulation by modeling more of the real device characteristics, but I think a spice model is fairly useless here anyway as evidenced that the model people frequently use is so simple it can be solved on paper. As for an opamp, depends if the output voltage you expect lines up with the input voltage of your ADC. My guess is you need one, but not necessarily.

Answer (score -2):

Your model is wrong for your operating point. First you need to understand there are too operating regimes for photodiodes: photovoltaic mode and photoconductive mode. Photovoltaic mode operates the photodiode like a tiny solar cell (no applied volage bias; photoconductive mode operates the photodiode with a reverse  bias and the current generated is proportional to the incident light absorbed (plus a tiny bit of dark current that leaks due to the applied bias). This is likely the operating mode you will use for your application.

In the first circuit that you are trying to emulate, the diode is operating in photoconductive mode PROVIDED the voltage dropped across the load resistor does not approach the bias voltage - this would bring the diode out of photoconductive mode. If the resistor is too large for the current generated by the diode, the bias is lost. If the resistor is too small, your signal suffers. However, you can achieved fast response times at the expense of a diminished signal amplitude.

Lets look at your simulated results. In the first case, you are using an ideal current source in Parallel with a large resistor (and capacitor but this capacitor has no effect on steady-state (DC) operation). You can only model a photodiode like this provided a reverse-bias is maintained across the diode junction. The simulation does not take this into account and will maintain that current invariant of any voltage bias - that is what an ideal current source does. The capacitor in the simulation is responsible for the transient behavior in the simulation. If you change this capacitor value, the first-order response changes but the steady-state operation will be the same for any value capacitor. So this simulation is working exactly as expected as shown, but it doesn't represent proper operation of a photodiode when the photocurrent gets too high.

The second circuit seems like an accurate model of the photodiode behavior - the max voltage is below (what would be a reverse bias voltage) if this was in a real circuit. It's worth noting that the junction capacitance is a function of reverse bias voltage across the junction - the capacitance goes down with an increase in reverse bias, thus the response will be faster. You have two capacitance values in the datasheet with their respective reverse bias voltage (6nF @ 1V and 4.5nf @ 3V). FWIW, your simulation is using 10nF as the junction capacitance.

Your last simulation is basically a filtered version of your previous simulation due to the added capacitance - your shifting the dominant pole to the left.

To answer your 2nd question - you should do both, at the same time. What you want is a circuit called a photodiode transimpedance amplifier. It requires only 4 parts plus the power supply: The photodiode, opamp, gain resistor, and low-pass/stability capacitor. The resistor sets the DC gain and depends on your photo signal. The capacitor is used to first stabilize the feedback loop and then it can be increased further to lower the pass-band frequency (noise filtering). The added benefit of this circuit is it maintains zero volts across the diode eliminating the dark current offset.

Comment: I see I will open a new question about it. Im interested in average DC output. What BW opamp I need?

Comment: That will depend on both speed and signal strength (A/W). Look into gain-bandwidth product. If you want the average DC signal follow the op-amp with a low-pass filter, or a 2 stage filter, or a combination of filtering and processing on the MCU.

Comment: I want want the average DC signal . so what should be gain BW product?

Comment: First consider the laser specs - wavelength and output power (CW or pulsed with the known duty cycle).  You have to derate the sensitivity (A/W) of the photodiode if the wavelengths don't perfectly match. Then you have to consider how much of the laser is incident to the photodiode - typically part of the beam would be sampled by a beam splitter and the rest of the laser light would be used for something more useful. Are there any other optics in place? Now you can estimate the gain you will need. The bandwidth doesn't matter much if the laser is operating quasi-CW.

Comment: CW? Did you read the question? I already mentioned "pulsed laser where its optical pulse train's pulse width is 0.5 ns and pulse period is 333 ns." Yes it will be portion of it. And I need average voltage as output which corresponds to laser power. I can calibrate.

Comment: @floppy380 Yes I read the question. But what what you don't know is that you can operate a CW laser in various pulsed modes such as your application. You did not describe the laser properties at all - other than how you are operating it in your application. If you have a diode laser, for example, it will have a CW output power spec at a given current level (sometimes a curve).  In first order, you will have 0.15% of this value.

Comment: @floppy380 On second thought, if you can calibrate it and you lack the understanding of theory, just set the laser output power to its maximum power setting. Then, adjust the gain until the signal is high enough for the down stream ADC.